The function is working on individual strings however not performing the same on dataframe column values
I am transforming strings, and retriving start and end dates to make a range out of this, to later build a graph. The function return all years between(inclusive of boundaries) if there are two dates. If there is one where string begins from '20' it returns lists until 2024. and otherwise it returns a single year.
Expected output is a list with years in range of start and end value of the years.
ex.
#input '(1992—1997)' 
#ouput [1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997]
for inputs like this '(декабрь 1997 — сентябрь 1998)'
its working properly, output: [1997, 1998]

the_dataframe
the function is not working on some inputs like: and returning only a single output (the end year). There are no error messages but the logic seemes to be wrong somewhere. I tried to pass individual string copy of the data in the df, and it worked. However when applying a function on a column, some rows return only one values instead of a range
(1996—1997) #iloc[25] #an example of a faulty row

def unpack_dates(year_range):
    years = year_range.replace('—', ' ').replace('-', ' ').replace('–', ' ').strip('(').strip(')').split()
    end = 2024
    unpacked  = [int(word) for word in years if word.isdigit() and len(word)==4]
    if len(unpacked)==2:
        return(list(range(unpacked[0], unpacked[1]+1)))
    elif len(unpacked)==1 and str(unpacked[0]).startswith('202'):
        return(list(range(unpacked[0], end+1)))
    else:
        return unpacked[0]


Specifically for your issue, it is because there is leading whitespace in some of your fields. This is the actual value in your faulty row
' (1996—1997)'

You remove the leading parentheses with .strip('(') which will only strip leading and trailing characters. Since there is whitespace, it doesn't remove the parenthesis.
' (1996—1997)'.replace('—', ' ').replace('-', ' ').replace('–', ' ').strip('(') 

Output
' (1996 1997)'

Adding .strip() prior to removing the parentheses solves the problem.
def unpack_dates(year_range):
    years = year_range.strip().replace('—', ' ').replace('-', ' ').replace('–', ' ').strip('(').strip(')').split()
    end = 2024
    unpacked  = [int(word) for word in years if word.isdigit() and len(word)==4]
    if len(unpacked)==2:
        return(list(range(unpacked[0], unpacked[1]+1)))
    elif len(unpacked)==1 and str(unpacked[0]).startswith('202'):
        return(list(range(unpacked[0], end+1)))
    else:
        return unpacked[0]

That said, there are some other ways of doing this that might've been less trouble. You can use regex to extract year-like patterns. In your case you can easily see that in your data, you never have years with less than 4 digits and never have any other numbers that are not years, but also have 4 digits. Below is how I would've written the function to be a bit more readable.
import re 

def unpack_dates(year_range):
    #First we extract all instances of exactly 4 digit characters in a row. Then we convert the list of strings to a list of integers 
    unpacked = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d{4}', year_range)))
    #Then we set the start year as the first value in our list. 
    start = unpacked[0]
    #If there is no end date, we want 2024 as our end year
    end = 2024
    if len(unpacked) == 1 and unpacked[0] < 2020:
        #If there is only 1 year found and it is less than 2020 then change the end year to the only year found
        end = unpacked[0]
    if len(unpacked) == 2:
        #If there are two items in unpacked then set the end year as the second item  
        end = unpacked[1]

    return list(range(start, end + 1))

df['worked'].apply(lambda x: unpack_dates(x)) 

This will work for your use case, particularly since your data is small enough to quickly look over it and see that you're covering all cases, but for large data sets you would have to worry about years not being 4 digits, 4 digit non-year strings (and what would happen if it finds more than 2 cases of 4 digit strings), what would happen if there are no 4 digit year strings, etc..
